# MaterialButton Style not working on Android 5.0 (api 21)

Tags: android, material-design, android-button, android-styles

Although they use the same code base, my problem is that they show different button styles. On Android 5.1 and above my code works as expected. But on Android 5.0 **MaterialButton** style and background color doesn't work.

I'm using `com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha01`

*Continue button* works on Nexus 5 Android 5.1.1
[image: Continue button works on Nexus 5 Android 5.1.1]

*Continue button* style does not work on Nexus 5 Android 5.0
[image]

This is `dialog.xml`

```
<com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

   <!-- View -->

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_allow"
            style="@style/Widget.AppTheme.ConfirmButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin_20"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_16"
            android:text="@string/str_continue" />

</com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

My **style.xml** is

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/onColorSecondary</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>

        <item name="textAppearanceButton">@style/TextAppearance.AppTheme.Button</item>

    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Widget.AppTheme.ConfirmButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
        <item name="android:backgroundTint">?colorSecondary</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">?colorOnSecondary</item>>
        <item name="cornerRadius">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/margin_12</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/margin_12</item>
        <item name="android:letterSpacing">-0.02</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextAppearance.AppTheme.Button" parent="TextAppearance.MaterialComponents.Button">
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">17sp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Android X instead of appcompat

with using material design try to use android X for the future. It is standard practice for the Material design.